# How to deal the null pointer without exit?

Tags: c++, winapi, null-pointer

When i got the null pointer, is there a better way to deal the null point instead of `MessageBox` and exit? My teacher told me it is not a good way to  use `exit()`. Here is my code:

```
CCheckBoxUI *pCbSwitch = static_cast<CCheckBoxUI*> (pItem->FindSubControl(_T("switch")));
    ASSERT(pCbSwitch && "Failed to find contronl");
    if (pCbSwitch == nullptr)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, _T("Failed to find contronl"), _T("tip"), 0);
        exit(-1);
    }
```

Comment: If you don't want to call exit, don't.

Comment: You already have the assert. Why are you double-checking?

Comment: @molbdnilo As what i know, the ASSERT will be void in the release. So this assert will be ignored.

Comment: You could use `return` so you could get back to your main function to do some cleanup (close file handlers and such) before you exit your program. Or you could write an error handler function that generates the message box, logs the error, does the cleanup and exits the program.

Comment: I believe the handle way is highly depend on business logic

Comment: Checking twice is clearly wrong. Once only. As to how to handle failure that is for you to decide. We can't decide for you.

Comment: One of the many ways you can deal with errors is throwing exceptions and "catching" them. The benefit is, when this is enclosed in a try {} catch () {} block then you can stop executing that block and you can handle the exception in the catch() block.

Comment: @Darktega: Exceptions are caught way too often. It is, however, common practice to throw exceptions when there aren't any exception handlers. This leads to a controlled shutdown of the program. Helpful in situations where you don't know how to deal with a certain error.

Comment: Did a prior teacher teach you to always exit in the case of an error? Alternatively, did they vaguely insinuate that an exception will always wind up quitting a program? Substitute teacher for book or online tutorial where appropriate. It sounds to me like you haven't yet made the epiphany about error handling being no different from other code, so finding the source of the confusion can help.

Comment: @IInspectable Yes, it depends heavily on how you want to deal with the problem. Is the error you are dealing with a possible data insufficiency in your system? (Therefore the null pointer) Probably you want to throw an exception and deal with it in a higher scoope.

Answer (score 4):

Probably the safest way is to ignore the possible null pointer. It's your control, and **you** know you put a `switch` element on it, so  you know `FindSubControl` will succeed. `FindSubControl` itself doesn't know that, which is why it documented to potentially return a null pointer.

Sure, you may have a bug, but that's why you have the assert in debug builds.

Answer (score 1):

Can `pItem->FindSubControl(_T("switch"))` **really** fail?

unless you don't have other function adding or removing subcontrols form your one ... the only failure can be a typo in the control name.

This is not "normal behavior" but a bug that your debug version catch with the assertion.
After the bug is corrected, no failure are possible, so no other check make sense.

Unless... you are in so restricted memory space that may be the framework is unable to create the control, so you cannot *get* it. But that's a situation you shold already know while creating the sub-controls. But in that case... even displaying a message box can be impossible!

In any case, if you want to be defensive e gracefully exit, don't call exit, but throw an exception. You can catch it in the caller (or in main) and exit in a cleaned up way.

Comment: *"You can catch it in the caller (or in main) and exit in a cleaned up way."* - Or don't catch it and exit in a controlled fashion just as much.

Comment: @IInspectable: of course. The problem is how much you want to be "fair" with the user. A GUI app that shuts down with no messages sets the user in WTF mode!

Comment: Shutting down in a controlled fashion does not imply immediate shutdown without any feedback. You can set your own terminate handler ([std::set_terminate](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/set_terminate)) for example. On Windows you could set an unhandled exception filter ([SetUnandledExceptionFilter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680634.aspx)), and get the exception record to write a meaningful dump file ([MiniDumpWriteDump](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680360.aspx)).